# Analogue of Princeton Companion to Mathematics for Physics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, specific-reference, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism

I would like to know if there are compendiums much like the Princeton Companion to Mathematics for physics (especially classical physics: fluid mechanics, elasticity theory, Hamiltonian formalism of classical mechanics, statistical mechanics etc etc).

Comment: Landau & Lifshitz?

Answer (score 4):

[**Frank Wilczek** will edit The Princeton Companion to Physics](http://blog.press.princeton.edu/2015/01/22/frank-wilczek-to-edit-the-princeton-companion-to-physics/), but unfortunately the anticipated publication date is in 2018. [Edit: the new anticipated date is 2020, see https://www.frankawilczek.com/single-post/2018/01/18/Princeton-Companion-to-Physics ]

Answer (score 3):

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62190/mathematical-equivalent-of-feynmans-lectures-on-physics) the Companion was suggested as a math equivalent of the Feynman Lectures on Physics.  If this is an equivalence relation it should be symmetric.

Comment: Feynman lectures on Physics is outdated and not really useful. Better books that cover more like Shankars.

Comment: It's absurd to say that the Feynman Lectures aren't useful - some facts in them are outdated, but you don't read Feynman for the facts.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't especially similar to *The Princeton Companion*, but I think that Thorne and Blandford's [Applications of Classical Physics](http://www.pma.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2008/) covers those topics you mentioned well, except for the formalism of classical mechanics.